We can't retrieve EmbeddedServiceBranding. Why we can't do it? How can we retrieve and migrate this metadata?
Per metadata api coverage report,
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/62
EmbeddedServiceBranding is supported by Metadata API and source tracking.

However, when we execute command to retrieve these metadata settings,
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.252.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_embeddedservicebranding.htm
sf force source retrieve -m EmbeddedServiceBranding  
 ›   Warning: @salesforce/cli update available from 2.53.6 to 2.55.6.
Warning: This command is deprecated and will be removed from Salesforce CLI on November 6, 2024. Use the "project retrieve start" command instead.
Retrieving v60.0 metadata from org using the v61.0 SOAP API
Preparing retrieve request... done
=== Retrieved Source

No results found

nothing happens and also if we try to retrieve them from VS Code.
What is going wrong?

Update!  EmbeddedServiceBranding is branding metadata for the legacy Salesforce Chat deployment. If we need to retrieve branding metadata for MIAW deployment, we need instead to retrieve and deploy
EmbeddedServiceConfig and BrandindSet metadata components.
SF also provided a new article about this https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=002774306&type=1
EmbeddedServiceConfig has a reference to branding set
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmbeddedServiceConfig xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <areGuestUsersAllowed>false</areGuestUsersAllowed>
    <branding>EmbeddedServiceConfig_BrandingSet_RandomNumber</branding>

BrandingSet metadata contains headerColor brandingSetProperty
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BrandingSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>headerTextColor</propertyName>
        <propertyValue>#FFFFFF</propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>headerColor</propertyName>
        <propertyValue>#FF8775</propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>

We can retrieve and deploy these settings to change Einstein bot Icon color.
Also, these are duplicated as Data records.
So if we need to update them, we can query them and update
First, get the BrandingSet Id by executing this script
bsId=$(sf data query -q "Select BrandingId  FROM EmbeddedServiceConfig WHERE DeveloperName = 'CUSAESC'" -t  --json  | jq '.result.records[0].BrandingId' -r)

Then you may query the BrandingSetProperty records by executing the following query
sf data query -q "SELECT Id, PropertyName, PropertyValue FROM BrandingSetProperty WHERE PropertyName = 'headerColor' AND BrandingSetId = '$bsId'" --json > headerColor.json

hcbspId=$(cat headerColor.json | jq '.result.records[0].Id' -r)

cat headerColor.json | jq '.result.records[0].PropertyValue' -r

If you need to update the header color, just execute
desiredValue=#C0C0C0
sf data update -s BrandingSetProperty -i $hcbspId -v PropertyValue=$desiredValue

